# Calling JavaScript Function From CodeBehind fails to fill getElementbyID

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, getelementbyid

I have to fill hidden elements in a form which gets posted. The elements get filled when you click a button which posts the form.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <!-- setting all the hidden fields --->
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function fnGetPara() {
            document.getElementById('EPS_MERCHANT').value     = bta_merchant;
            document.getElementById('EPS_TXNTYPE').value      = bta_txntype;
            document.getElementById('EPS_REFERENCEDID').value = bta_referenceId;
            document.getElementById('EPS_AMOUNT').value       = bta_amount;
            document.getElementById('EPS_TIMESTAMP').value    = bta_timestamp;
            document.getElementById('EPS_FINGERPRINT').value  = bta_fingerprint;
            document.getElementById('EPS_RESULTURL').value    = bta_jumpback;
        }
    </script>
    <!-- finish setting all the hidden fields --->
<form method="post" action="https://....." id="form1" runat="server">
 <div class="docdisplay">     
    <!-- merchant -->
    <input type="hidden" name="EPS_MERCHANT"  id="EPS_MERCHANT" />
    <!-- transaction -->
    <input type="hidden" name="EPS_TXNTYPE"   id="EPS_TXNTYPE" />
    <!-- reference -->
    <input type="hidden" name="EPS_REFERENCEDID" id="EPS_REFERENCEDID"/>
    <!-- amount to be paid -->
    <input type="hidden" name="EPS_AMOUNT"  id="EPS_AMOUNT" />
    <!-- Timestamp -->
    <input type="hidden" name="EPS_TIMESTAMP" id="EPS_TIMESTAMP"/>
     <!-- fingerprint -->
    <input type="hidden" name="EPS_FINGERPRINT" id="EPS_FINGERPRINT" />
    <!-- where we want to go after the payment -->
    <input type="hidden" name="EPS_RESULTURL" id="EPS_RESULTURL" />
    ....
</div>
<div class="docbuttons">
   <asp:Button ID="lblauth" runat="server" Text="Authorise payment" OnClick="lblauth_Click"  />
</div>
```

and the method:

```
protected void lblauth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get bank transaction data
    bankTransAct.setTransactValues(orderId, invoiceNo, orderpaid, out bta_merchant, out bta_pw, out bta_txntype, out bta_amount, out bta_referenceId, out bta_timestamp, out bta_fingerprint);

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallfnGetPara", "fnGetPara()", true);
}
```

The **"bankTransAct"** method collects the value for these hidden fields.

I have tried the id values with EPS or without .value. The fields bta_fields are defined like this:

```
public partial class smsfannrm5 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
//global variables 
....

string  bta_merchant    = string.Empty;
string  bta_pw          = string.Empty;
string  bta_txntype     = string.Empty;
decimal bta_amount      = 0;
string  bta_referenceId = string.Empty;
string  bta_timestamp   = string.Empty;
string  bta_fingerprint = string.Empty;
string  bta_jumpback    = string.Empty;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{........
```

Each time I trace the page it shows me that the hidden fields are not filled?!
When I fill the hidden fields manually the page works.

Appreciate any feedback. I cannot see where I made the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do at least one of:

- access ASP.NET variables, e.g. `bta_merchant`, from JavaScript; or
- have ASP.NET codebehind read the value of an HTML `input` which has not been marked as `runat="server"`

This doesn't work, since the client's JavaScript engine is not connected to your ASP.NET server back-end.

I'm guessing your use-case here, but I think what you want to do is make all the hidden `input`s server-side controls, i.e. accessible from your codebehind C#. If that's the case, declare them as

```
<input type="hidden" name="whatever"  id="whatever" runat="server" />
```

and then set their value from codebehind, not JavaScript. You'll be able to read their values on post-back, or they'll be submitted with the form data if you're submitting to a third-party payment gateway or whatever.

If it is necessary to access the HTML element from JavaScript, ASP.NET will render an ID attribute which is different to the C# property name, so you'll need use the `ClientID` property:

```
<script>
var element = document.getElementById('<%= serverSideObject.ClientID %>');
</script>
```

---

If the name and ID of the generated *client side* element are important, and you don't ever need that value back (i.e. if the form never gets posted-back), then you can do the opposite:

- Make the hidden `input` a regular old HTML form element, *not* a server-side element
- use an embedded display expression (`<%= … %>`) [(see introduction to inline expressions here)](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/976112) to add the correct value

In this case, you'd write something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="whatever"  id="whatever" value="<%= someCSharpExpression %>" />
```

Note that the element is *not* a server-side element; it doesn't have the `runat="server"` attribute. Therefore ASP.NET won't mangle the element name or ID. The only special thing that ASP.NET is doing is evaluating `someCSharpExpression`, converting it to a string, and inserting it instead of the `<%= … %>`.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. 
There is one last question:
to fill this hidden fields with a string how to I have to convert the string?
e.g EPS_MERCHANT (TEXT) = bta_Merchant (STRING)

Comment: EPS_MERCHANT.Value = bta_merchant; ?

Comment: all works great however now I come into problems that by runat ASP.NET changes my name attribute which can not happening as the form gets posted to a bank for payment. Any ideas as I found answers for id but not name?

Comment: OK, so in that case you're just writing the correct value in to the hidden field when you render the page, and you never expect a post-back? In that case, this will work better:
`<input type="hidden" name="EPS_MERCHANT"  id="EPS_MERCHANT" value="<%= bta_merchant %>" />`

Comment: Can I remove the id as well?

Comment: With the previous comment's approach, yes; it's no longer a server side control. Most of the `input` declaration gets sent from the server as-is, only the `<%=` gets evaluated in C#. You can do whatever you like outside the `<%=…%>`, as long as it makes sense to the client.

Comment: This link might explain things better than I can: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/976112

Comment: all great but ASP.NET still lets me down with         <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00" type="hidden" value="&lt;%= bta_merchant %>" /> instead of <input name="EPS_MERCHANT".... >

Comment: if I remove the runat="server" it tells me that bta_merchant is inaccessible due to its protection level. I assume I have built the filling differently then?

Comment: Just make `bta_merchant` a public member. Maybe protected will do. I don't understand the access protection relationship between ASP.NET inline code and code-behind classes very well, sorry.

Comment: public might be not good as the bank said it needs to be put into a hidden field. I can try but then someone can get the value?

Comment: Well, you're already making the value extremely public by putting it on the internet! (Even if it's in a hidden field, people can still e.g. look at the source.) This is pretty far outside the scope of the original question, though, so if you have more general questions, could you try finding someone in chat?